# Server-side Reading of ID3 tags with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, mp3, id3

I have been searching for a few weeks to find a solution that will allow me to read id3 tags from an mp3 file that has been uploaded to Google App Engine. The uploaded files are stored in the Blobstore and I am coding with Java.

I would like to request assistance with two tasks:

1. I would like to have access to a library or method that can read id3 info from the most popular audio file formats. I have experimented with some libraries that can do this, but they all require access to java.io.File which is not supported by GAE. Therefore, the frames/tags must be read from memory or from some other GAE supported access method.
2. I would like to know how to get the bytes from the doPost method rather than hitting the blobstore again.

Below is the code that I wish to complete:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("aud-file");

    BlobKey fileKey = blobKeys.get(0);
    BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(fileKey);
    String filename = info.getFilename();
    long size = info.getSize();
    Date created = info.getCreation();
    String key = info.getBlobKey().getKeyString();

    // TODO: Get mp3 file that was just uploaded and retrieve ID3 tag 
    //       info.

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat();
    formatter.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>");
    builder.append("<file name=\"" + filename + "\" ");
    builder.append("size=\"" + Long.toString(size) + "\" ");
    builder.append("created=\"" 
            + formatter.format(created).toString() + "\" ");
    builder.append("key=\"" + key + "\">");

    // TODO: append Title, Artist, and Duration of audio file for 
    //       response to client side code

    builder.append("</file>");

    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=\"utf-8\"");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.write(builder.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

The code above is working and seems to be a good pattern for anyone who wants to retrieve information from an uploaded file. (If testing locally in Eclipse, be sure to set your bindAddress flag to the local machine name and also add that same name as a host to GWT Developer Plugin options.) Thanks in advance for any assistance with this request.

Chris

Comment: Whats wrong with using the blobstore?

Comment: Hi Shay, I am using the blobstore. My problem is that I am trying to read id3 data from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). The only problem is that it requires a readable `java.io.File`.

To make this work you can try using [`File` wrapper for GAE](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-java-io/source/browse/trunk/src/com/vobject/appengine/java/io/File.java?r=12). An example using it is [here](http://code.google.com/p/project-nivt-mediavault/source/browse/tags/release_1.3.2/src/file/management/EditMP3MetadataServlet.java?r=457).

Comment: Hi Peter, this may take a little bit of time to verify, but I will give it a shot and see if it works. I will be sure to document my results.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use blobstore and createUploadUrl to upload files the data is already in the blobstore and you can **only** access it using blobstore API.

Answer (score 0):

Using GAE for storage of any kind of larger files is not such a good idea.
According to this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) there are hard limits to request/response times and also for the amount of data that can be transferred:

- Response must return within 60 seconds (assuming you have a large file and slow connection this could be a problem)
- request can be max 1MB large (not shure of this)
- response can be max 32 MB large
- also I think there is a 1MB limit of entry in blob store (so even if you manage to get the file there, you would have to split the file into multiple entries)

i think it would be good if you just make a few tests before doing some real work there.